# Finally is it bad to mention words around sex in your page?

Tags: seo, keywords, search

Among other I run a humor site, developed in php. I have a custom search built where people search for everything under the sun.

I have noticed that it helps me to have a "Latest searches section" where I list the latest searches performed.

As you can understand I have a lot of searches that are "naughty". Not because I have anything offensive on the site, but I guess it's what some people want to find. Most of the time what they actually find is jokes around the subject or some video of a stand up talking about the search item.

The question I have is. Should I filter out these terms from my page? I am afraid that the site might get blocked from office firewalls and maybe banned by an advertising network (like adsense) just because some stupid robot found a term that thought in the sites' text.

One thing that you might ask is: If the site is family safe, how come all these people search for "naughty" terms. 2 reasons.

- Google. Many times people looking for something sexy linked to a strange object (e.g. sex and lion or dog or oak tree) end up to my site. Of course they don't find what they are looking for, so they hit search which is pre-filled with the term that led them to the site. After that the term goes in latest searches.
- Whether A happens or just a users types in something "naughty", this term's popularity is beeing reenforced by the fact that many people see it in latest searches, click on it and search for it again. So if someone searches for "funny hat" the term dissappears from latest searches within minutes. If he types something more spicy, other people click on it and it remains in the latest searches for hours.

Once again I want to clarify that the site has ZERO nudity and it doesn't even have sexy videos. YouTube is way more sexier that my site.

thanks for anyone spending the time to share his knowledge.

Update: Although [John Conde](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16449/finally-is-it-bad-to-mention-words-around-sex-in-your-page/16450#16450) did give it a shot, I think the dillema at hand is still on. Should I remove controversial terms from the text of a non-controversial site? I know for a fact that Google might ban a site that it "thinks" is porn related. Is the risk worth it? What would you do?

Comment: +1 for making an SO question with "sex" in the title, and for making a website which "YouTube is way more sexier" than.

Comment: Hm... maybe L2[P.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)? Or maybe [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info).

Comment: @Kerrek SB :)  I see the irony but this is a fact. There are quite a lot of videos on YouTube that are popular only because there is some cleavage on the thumb or it is a hot half naked teen blond talking about [put whatever random comes to mind here]. Many such videos are reuploaded by others just to promote some service or site though the description.

Comment: My suggestion would be only listing search terms that actually yielded some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that this wouldn't affect your Adsense account since the actual content of your website is not sexual in nature. Additionally, having a word mentioned once or twice on a page, and sometimes not at all since newer searches can bump them off of the page, will have little impact on that page's relevancy for adult-related phrases.

Having said that, I would recommend filtering out those words as they can only do you harm as you have suggested (filtering software blocking your site, etc). Since your site does not contain the kind of content implied by those search terms there is no reason to give those search terms prominent placement on your website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the interesting thing is that this traffic has value to me. There are people coming to the site and then even though they don't find what they are looking for, they stay for the content. I average 2.2 p.v./visit out of these terms.

But what I would really like some input is whether this can prove a bigger loss than a win.

e.g. if the site is blocked by corporate firewalls, and adsense bans me, and google starts dealing the site as adult related this might actually level the traffic gain I currently have. Or even decrease my traffic.